# Building function where the output is graphic

Tags: graphics, functions

I want to build a function, where the inputs are points and voronoimesh, and points. But, the output would be a graphics parameter. the code is following:

```
   pts = ImageCorners[img4, MaxFeatures -> 20];
   Vmesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
   cluster1[{pts, Vmesh}]
   cluster1[{pts_, Vmesh_}] := Block[{t16, t17},
   t16 = Graphics[{Green, {PointSize[0.05], Point[pts]}, Blue, 
   MeshPrimitives[Vmesh, 1], {Opacity[0.1], 
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Yellow}], FaceForm[Yellow]}}];
   t17 = Graphics[{Thick, Green, 
  Line[pts[[Last[FindShortestTour[pts]]]]]}]]
  Show[img4, t16, t17]
```

Here, img4 can be any image. Please choose any image.

But, this is not working when I am showing the image. How to solve the problem? It must have to be done with function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would change your code, if I actually understand what you intend:

```
(* Load a sample image to work on *)
img4 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}];

(* This is your code *)
pts = ImageCorners[img4, MaxFeatures -> 20];
Vmesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];

(* This is modified to avoid localized variables *)
(* and to use a single Graphics expression *)
cluster1[{pts_, Vmesh_}] :=
 Graphics[{
   Green, PointSize[0.05], Point[pts],
   Blue, MeshPrimitives[Vmesh, 1],
   Thick, Green, Line[pts[[Last[FindShortestTour[pts]] ] ]] 
   }]

(* Show your results *)
Show[img4, cluster1[{pts, Vmesh}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The main reason why your code was not working was scoping: you had localized your variables `t16` and `t17` within `Block` so they were not accessible from outside your `cluster1` function.

Additionally, you did not really need to have two Graphics expressions; you can use a single long one containing all your graphics objects and directives.

Finally, the last three directives in your `Graphics` expression for `t16` referred to no object and were unused (`{Opacity[0.1], 
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Yellow}], FaceForm[Yellow]}`). Were you perhaps missing a graphics object there?

---

**Update:**

Since you would like to retain the separation between the two Graphics objects, you can still create them separately within `cluster1` and assign them to internal module variables, then return them in a list from the cluster1 function, and assign them to any global variables you want.

In principle, you *could* also modify the `t16` and `t17` global variables directly from within the `cluster1` function, but I'd advise against that: it may become hard to track possible bugs if your functions have such side effects.

For instance, the following code will return the same exact result as the version presented above:

```
Clear[cluster1]
cluster1[{pts_, Vmesh_}] :=
 Module[
   {a, b},
   a = Graphics[{
        Green, {PointSize[0.05], Point[pts]},
        Blue, MeshPrimitives[Vmesh, 1]
       }];
   b = Graphics[{Thick, Green, Line[pts[[Last[FindShortestTour[pts]]]]]}];
   {a, b}
 ]

{t16, t17} = cluster1[{pts, Vmesh}];
Show[img4, t16, t17]
```

Comment: Hi Marco, Thanks a lot. Actually, my purpose of this question is to learn when there are variables like t16,t17 how the functions can work. It's because, I have a very big code where before the graphics values I some calculation then the final output is some graphics value. Here, I just give a small demonstration. Also, I need them separated; not in one image for my research. So, I really want to know, is there any way, I can do it with the variables?

Comment: @Odrisso Yes it can certainly be done; please take a look at the updated code at then end of my answer above.

Comment: Hi Marco, The code is giving the following error:

Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[.....]

Comment: @Odrisso Do you have assigned values for `img4`, `pts` and `Vmesh`? Try clearing these variables and then re-running their assignments, i.e. the first three lines of the first version of my answer.

Comment: HI, Thanks. It worked. However, I have another minor problem. It is not related to graphics. The problem is: in my function, I used some calculation and where some redundant second brackets come. Now, to remove those redundant brackets, I used "PP1 = PP1 //. {x_List} :> x" one. The problem is this gives the following error: "Tag Times in PP1 {} is Protected". How can I solve this one?

Comment: @Odrisso It's hard to say without knowing the structure of PP1, but I suggest that you use `Flatten` to remove extra layers of braces, rather than a replacement rule; that seems much safer. Since this has nothing to do with the current question, though, perhaps you could post it as another question.